# How to appy several conditional formatting in devexpress gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

could you please be so kind to point me where is a mistake in the following code? I'm tring to apply color to row based on column value:

```
<dxg:GridControl ...>
<dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
    <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[Days] &lt;= '50' And IsNullOrEmpty([Status])" FieldName="Days" ApplyToRow="True" IsEnabled="True">
        <dx:Format Background="#FF8DF78D"/>
    </dxg:FormatCondition>
    <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[Days] &gt; '50' And [Days] &lt;= '120' And IsNullOrEmpty([Status])" FieldName="Days" ApplyToRow="True" IsEnabled="True">
        <dx:Format Background="#FFF8FC77"/>
    </dxg:FormatCondition>
    <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[Days] &gt; '120' And IsNullOrEmpty([Status])" FieldName="Days" ApplyToRow="True" IsEnabled="True">
        <dx:Format Background="#FFFAA0A0"/>
    </dxg:FormatCondition>
</dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Days" UnboundType="Integer" UnboundExpression="DateDiffDay([DateCounted], LocalDateTimeToday())" Visible="True">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
         <dxe:TextEditSettings Mask="d"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Problem is that only "more than 120" rule applied, tow others are not applied.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @rolls Nope, solution wasn't found...

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm thinking I will have to simply write a wrapper and manually set the cell backgrounds and call their equivalent of redraw. It should be more performant, but it will be ugly and not fit in nicely with my other MVVM stuff. And if I set it manually I might as well just use the stock WPF one and do everything manually.

Comment: @rolls just no color filling is done, that's all what I finished with...